# using jquery to set and read cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using jquery cookie plugin and trying to set cookie and read cookie betwen browser sessions:

I have this piece of code to set the cookie using jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $.cookie("example", "foo", { path: 'C:/temp', expires: 7 }); 
        alert( $.cookie("example") );
    });

</script>
```

I get undefined error. Any ideas?

Comment: please indicate which plugin is the one you're using... there's more than one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you misunderstood what the path option is for.

Note: I'm assuming you're using this plugin: [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

The following should work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/', expires: 7 }); 
        alert( $.cookie("example") );
    });
```

From the documentation:

> Define the path where the cookie is valid. By default the path of the
>   cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was created (standard
>   browser behavior). If you want to make it available for instance
>   across the entire domain use path: '/'. Default: path of page where
>   the cookie was created.

As you can see, it expects the path of the page, not a local path.

Comment: yes, thank you. One more question. Once I set the cookie, how do I read this from another browser session? How do I pass this to another browser session? Based on the cookie, I need to change the title of the page.

Comment: you get the cookie with: `$.cookie("example")`, like in your example. Do you know how HTTP cookies work? You need the current page to be in the same path (or below) that you specified for the cookie.